# Commons IO (Apache) copyURLToFile Not Working

Tags: java, apache-commons

I'm writing some code to automatically download files from a website given a set of links. I'm able to make an array of links by passing in the site, but the following code isn't working:

```
public static void downloadFiles(String[] links) {
    for (String link : links) {
        try {
            URL u = new URL(link);
            File f = new File("D:" + File.separator + "Java Programming" + File.separator + "File Downloader" + File.separator + "output" + File.separator + link.split("/")[link.split("/").length - 1]);
            //System.out.println(f.toString());
            FileUtils.copyURLToFile(u, f);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

I've imported the commons-io-2.6.jar file into eclipse and have done research online, but cannot find anyone with a solution. I've tried to run the code with and without the **output** directory already created, but in either case the files aren't downloaded. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: your code has no problem, could you please provide a link that is not working?

Comment: you should **not** ignore any exception to see why nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential problem could be that you are catching the exception and not handling it in any way, so if exception is thrown you don't get notified in any way. Try to print that exception's stack trace, and see if you get any exceptions thrown.

Anyway, what worked for me was using `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter`:

```
// Create URL object
URL url = new URL(singleUrl);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

File downloadedFile = new File(DOWNLOAD_FOLDER+generateFilename()+".html");

BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(downloadedFile));

// read each line from stream till end
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    writer.write(line);
}

reader.close();
writer.close();
```